# Most specific NFC-Tag-Intent-Filter possible?

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter

I'd like to detect all plain-text NDEF-NFC-Tags that have a certain prefix (e.g. `"mytagprefix1234567890"`. What is the most specific intent-filter I could use for this senario to make sure that my application has the highest priority when reading such a tag? Data-schemes can only be defined for Smart-Poster-URI-Tags, correct?

I'm currently using

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are controlling the tag contents, which it seems like you are, why not use a custom mime type or uri?

There isn't a more specific way to filter for this as text records are mapped to text/plain mime types, which are pretty general.

Comment: Thanks! I'm indeed controlling the tag-contents, but would like to stick to the prefix-variant and NDEF-Plain-Text, as I'd like my users to be able to use their own tags, and I guess writing "mytagprefix12354" with the NFC-Writer-App is easier than setting up a custom URI-Tag for the average user.